# Flask-sqlalchemy: When to close sessions?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have created a python webapp with Flask and it seems like I am having connection issues with the database. I think this is because I don't close my sessions somewhere in my code.

I have

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

for the database and use

```
@views.route('/test/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    db.session.add(something)
    db.session.commit()

@views.route('/another_page/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def page():
    some_records = User.query.get(some_ids)
```

for adding records to the database.

When do I have to close my session in this case? Is there a way to close the connection after the user leaves? Should I close every time a page is done with the database? Do I need to close my connection after a query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/patterns/sqlalchemy/?highlight=close#manual-object-relational-mapping) says next:

> As in the declarative approach, you need to close the session after each request or application context shutdown. Put this into your application module:

```
from yourapplication.database import db_session

@app.teardown_appcontext
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
    db_session.remove()
```

UPD: In case of Flask-SQLAlchemy this staff is [hardcoded](https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/e5bf821072de0d55ff92891432004322864a7265/src/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L873), thus you don't need to care about it when develop.

Comment: Note that [db.init_app()](https://github.com/pallets-eco/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/e5bf821072de0d55ff92891432004322864a7265/src/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L873) should automatically configure this.